# Finding the last $17$ digits of $1707 \uparrow \uparrow 1783$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, programming, tetration

The objective is to find the last $17$ digits of : $1707 \uparrow \uparrow 1783$. In other words:

$$
1707 \uparrow \uparrow 1783 \pmod{10^{17}}
$$

where $\uparrow \uparrow$ represents tetration or repeated exponentiation.

I have thought of a process that goes like this:

- Find $k$ such that:

$$
1707^{k} \equiv 1 \pmod{10^{17}}
$$

- Since $\text{gcd}(10^{17}, 1707) = 1 \longrightarrow k = \varphi(10^{17}) = 4 \cdot 10^{16}$
- Store that $k$ and repeat step $1$ for $\pmod{k}$.

After $51$ iterations, $k$ will be continuously $\varphi(1) = 1$ and there's no point in going further.

However I cannot think how to use these $51$ values of $k$ to yield the result. Can one elaborate on how to continue or suggest another method?

Comment: What does $\uparrow \uparrow$ mean?

Comment: Presumably tetration, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation

Comment: $ 3 \uparrow \uparrow 4 = 3^{3^{3^3}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference the number $1707 \uparrow \uparrow 1783$ uses [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) for [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). For every $n\in\Bbb{N}$, the number $1707\uparrow\uparrow n$ is the $n$-th term in the sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ defined by $s_0=1$ and $s_{n+1}=1707^{s_n}$.

To determine the remainder of $s_{1783}=1707 \uparrow \uparrow 1783$ after division by $10^{17}$ we repeatedly use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), which tells us that if $s_{1782}\equiv t_0\pmod{\varphi(10^{17})}$ then
$$s_{1783}=1707^{s_{1782}}\equiv1707^{t_0}\pmod{10^{17}}.$$
Repeating the same argument we see that, if $s_{1782-k}\equiv t_k\pmod{\varphi^k(10^{17})}$ then
$$s_{1783-k}=1707^{s_{1782-k}}\equiv1707^{t_k}\pmod{\varphi^{k-1}(10^{17})}.$$
Of course for positive integers $a$ and $b$ we have $\varphi(2^a5^b)=2^{a+1}5^{b-1}$,
so
$$\varphi^k(10^{17})=\begin{cases}
2^{17+k}5^{17-k}&\text{ if }k\leq17,\\
2^{51-k}&\text{ if }17\leq k\leq51,\\
1&\text{ if }k\geq51\end{cases},$$
and hence we may take $t_{50}=1$ as $\varphi^{50}(10^{17})=2$ and $s_{1732}\equiv1\pmod{2}$. As $\varphi^{49}(10^{17})=4$ it follows that
$$s_{1733}=1707^{s_{1732}}\equiv1707^1\equiv3\pmod{4},$$
and so we may take $t_{49}=3$. Repeating then yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
t_{49}=s_{1734}&=&1707^{s_{1733}}&\equiv&1707^3&\equiv&3^3\equiv3&\pmod{8},\\
t_{48}=s_{1735}&=&1707^{s_{1734}}&\equiv&1707^3&\equiv&11^3\equiv3&\pmod{16},\\
\vdots\\
t_{18}=s_{1765}&=&1707^{s_{1765}}&\equiv&1707^{5418148179}&\equiv&14008082771&\pmod{2^{34}},
\end{eqnarray*}
and now repeat a few more times to compute $t_0=s_{1783}\pmod{10^{17}}$.

Comment: Great answer. Just a minor correction: shouldn't $t_{48}$ be $3$?

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for catching that!

Comment: Since there is a significant amount of repeated factors, the [Carmichael function](https://tio.run/##ZVBBTsMwELz7FcMhEpgkjVsJLrg8JMrBTlJqk7rIUCGE@vawtpO0wMm7M@vZ2fEn/TW@tB1ksYXKofHNkAoJnUNlGp97M/QE3EhURPr@4@QdFDszNrSH3z9nsuR6RbK1ynXDzmOr/MG0e9UPcdzF2d3Rw8A4VGXpqAe079UrzA6uPHbdc8QcVhJrKnvXxQXv5Ews1TqMG8g0M2Gc35pifZeobWQs4Rt60zGWWzxJpK3/fVw7yex8@OLGxib5mXdSEjVVOWwhGnDaEDyIxUMSsLifLNvsIZgWV/CfGxdFFxSDFZIRl4yJo2RdSKPiXDyyN4TmEnXtmunc@HP8AQ) can be used instead to get the answer in only 19 steps, opposed to your 49 steps.

Comment: why is it $\phi(2^a5^b)= 2^{a+1}5^{b-1}$?